# Lagrangian density for Majorana particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

The Majorana fermion satisfies the equation
$$(i\tilde\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu -m)\psi=0,$$
where the matrices $\tilde\gamma^\mu$ satisfy the standard Dirac relations 
$$\{\tilde\gamma^\mu,\tilde\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu},$$
but they are purely imaginary, in the contrary to the usual Dirac matrices.

**Question.** How to get the Majorana equation from a Lagrangian density?

Actually in Execise 3.4 to Ch. 3 in the book "An introduction to QFT" by Peskin and Schroeder it is mentioned that it is possible to construct such a Lagrangian density if one considers the field $\psi$ taking values in Grassmann numbers. I am wondering whether Grassmann numbers are really necessary here and whether there exists a more standard approach to get the equations from a Lagrangian (like in the case of the usual Dirac equation).

Comment: see [Lagrangian and grassmann numbers](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130113/lagrangian-and-grassmann-numbers) (also, [Srednicki](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) discusses the Majorana Lagrangian in chapter 36)

Comment: The equation You wrote is not Majorana equation, it's just the Dirac equation written in particular basis of Dirac matrices (the so-called Majorana basis).

Comment: @NameYYY Majorana fermions are (always?) taken to satisfy the Majorana condition $\psi=\psi^c$, in which case the Majorana equation becomes identical to the Dirac equation. (this is similar to the case of the Klein-Gordon field: the real and complex fields satisfy the same equation).